# GPU vs CPU calculation

Tags: parallel-computing, gpu, complexity

I've been working on calculating large factorials ($N>10^9$) and I was wondering if it wasn't faster to use the GPU to run the calculations on something like openCL. What I realized however was that, not only I didn't know if it was worth it in that case, I couldn't tell when it is or isn't appropriate to use a GPU for number crunching. So, basically, what are the pros and cons of using GPU and CPU for such large numbers ($10^9!$) or when is it worth it at all to do GPU implementation?

Comment: Mathematical notation can be used in your posts here with [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$, although this is not supported on all StackExchange sites (nor on Meta.SciComp.SE).

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) tells me $10^9!$ will have over eight and a half billion digits.  If required, outputting the result in full would also take time regardless of how it is computed.

Comment: @hardmath I'm aware it will take time hahaha. I'm preparing 128Gb of DDR4 plus 4 512Gb SSDs on RAID 0 configuration to handle all the data. My options are an i7 extreme or two GTX980's tho for the calculation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need the exact value of the factorial of such a large number?

Comment: @hardmath, two reasons : why do people climb the everest? Because it's there! And to do some experimentation on testing cases for brown numbers (Brocard's problem). On a related note I'm on a hiatus between high-school and getting accepted to college, so I need to have some fun :)

Comment: My bad, that was to @HydroGuy

Comment: I'm asking that because the only use that I could see for something like that is either number theory or criptography, and, at least cryptography, i think wouldn't use brute force factorial calculation. Besides that, GPU is a pretty picky architecture, and things like small numbers x large numbers, that occur on factorials, is not something pleasant in any case, much less on a GPU

Comment: @HydroGuy I'm looking into implementing this http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/index.html let me know how you think it will play out. Just out of curiosity, which language do you code in?

Comment: I do most of my work in pure C, I have messed around with C+openCL and +cuda, and intend to use them more on the future, for calculations. I also program a bit of python and some other things, python specially I wish to use for scripting and repetitive work, which still isn't what I'm doing right now.

Comment: @HydroGuy, cool :). I do most of my stuff in python and I'm _really_ struggling with all this C++ coding for this project. All the language's formalism drives me crazy, and it's surprisingly difficult to find people who want to calculate 10^9! just for the challenge of it to help out.

Comment: About the fast factorial code: the first problem that you have to solve is how to not use recursions, because they simply don't exist on GPU (neither cuda C nor openCL C support it). The second problem is paralelizing the calculation, which I think it's fairly direct, if you think on the naive reduction version at least. I believe that the biggest problem that you are going to face is something like either overflow or big x small product number. Since you are mostly going to use some kind of big num library, I can't comment on performance because I don't have any experience with them.

Comment: Maybe I could make the CPU run the iteration and just throw the bad calculations for the GPU? I'm not sure how much of a drawback that would represent.

Comment: The problem is not 10^9, the problem is (10^9)!, which completely busts the usual int64 type that is native for the machine. The moment that you don't have hardware support, at least native support, things can get really messy and most people don't want to dive in without a really good reason, and, most of the time, 'just for the challenge' is not a good enough reason. 'For the challenge', I prefer so much more code a computational fluid dynamics or electromagnetic solver than trying to calculate a single ridiculously large number.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty long hiatus from now until july or so, I thought I'd better have something to do and that's something that had been going through my mind for a while. I think I'll give it a try eitherway, using Bignum and bare parallel CPU and then porting it over to GPU when I can.

Comment: Factorials are a bit too regular and predictable (usually people try $\pi$ or $\gamma$ - e.g., $\lfloor 10^{10^6}\pi\rfloor$). For example, $10^9!$ is divisible by $2^{10^9-13}$ and by $5^{(10^9-8)/4}$, so the least significant $\sim249,999,998$ decimal digits are just zeros - any computational effort on them is completely wasted.

Comment: @Kirill, I was looking into factorials so I could one day when I have the time implementing it on a Brocard Problem calculator. A Brown Number(Brocard's problem) is defined as $(a, b)$ where $a!+1 = b²$, such as $(4, 5)$. I'm just stubborn as hell with solving these pointless problems.

Comment: @Arengorn Ah, okay. I looked it up at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardsProblem.html and it cites Berndt & Galway - but they computed $n!+1$ modulo some primes, and then established whether a solution existed via the Chinese remainder theorem. That is *vastly* more efficient than computing $n!$ directly. They seem to have been using mid-1990's hardware, so I bet this should be easy now. Can I recommend that you ask a separate question explicitly stating the goal and all the context? You might get more direct/helpful responses for your actual problem.

Comment: @Kirill Absolutely, I will do so. This particular question just sprouted out of my curiosity whether GPU was a viable alternative for things like this, I'm glad I now know it isn't. I'll make a new question on the _big picture_ asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may have gone unnoticed in the comments under the original question, but computing $10^9!$ yields a number with 8.5 billion digits, that is it is on the order of $10^{9\cdot 10^9}$. Given that $10^{9\cdot 10^9}=1000^{3\cdot 10^9} \approx 1024^{3\cdot 10^9}=(2^{10})^{3\cdot 10^9}=2^{3\cdot 10^{10}}$, you need approximately $3\cdot 10^{10}$ bits, or around $4\cdot 10^9$ bytes to simply *represent* such a number. That's a sizable amount of memory.

Now imagine that you want to compute this number in parallel by having each processor compute a part of the factorial. For example, processor $p$ computes $Q_p=\prod_{k=N_{p-1}}^{N_p} k$, then the total can be computed by $N_P! = \prod_{p=1}^P Q_p$ if you choose $N_0=1$ and $P$ is the number of processors. But generally, each one of the $Q_p$ are going to be of the same order of magnitude as the final result (well, not quite, but you get the general idea), so if you have $P$ processors, you need to provision $P$ times as much memory as it takes to store the final result.

On a GPU, you have *many* processors, $P={\cal O}(1000)$. If each of the numbers you have to store already takes 4 GB of memory, then if you have to store it 1000 times over, you very quickly end up with an amount of memory that is not only not available on a typicaly GPU, but in fact not even in regular desktop computers.

I think what this means is that you are biting off more than you can likely chew if you try to compute $10^9!$.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit old, but the [CUDA Multiprecision Arithmetic Library](http://www.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~nakayama/cump/) probably supports the operations you need, and reports [2-4x speed-ups](http://www.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~nakayama/cump/index.php?CUMP%20Performance%20Evaluation) vs a CPU socket.  It claims to have a GMP-like interface, so porting you code could be straight-forward, relative to writing custom kernel code.

Comment: 2x-4x is not that impressive if the comparsion cpu is a 4-core i7

Comment: 2x-4x was against the dual socket opteron, which was the more relevant comparison in its day.  The website, and all the hardware on it, is out of date.

Comment: Ah, ok, this is much more interesting, I hadn't read the website, thanks for explaining

Comment: If GPU folks claim a speed up less than 10x, it's probably useless, because the majority of their performance claims are wildly exaggerated and tailored towards cases where they win.

Comment: @Jeff do you have a specific criticism of their performance analysis?  They avoid the cardinal sin of comparing to a single CPU core, which is the only way a GPU could ever top 10x, and they do a parameter sweep that includes some of the ramp-up region.  I'd like to also see vector lengths that were lower and operations with higher arithmetic intensity, sure, but what they have done seems common enough and robust.